# determining context from text using pandas

Tags: python, pandas, nltk, text-analysis

I've built a web crawler which fetches me data. The data is typically structured. But then and there are a few anomalies. Now to do analysis on top of the data I am searching for few words i.e `searched_words=['word1','word2','word3'......]` I want the sentences in which these words are present. So I coded as below :

```
searched_words=['word1','word2','word3'......]

fsa = re.compile('|'.join(re.escape(w.lower()) for w in searched_words))
str_df['context'] = str_df['text'].apply(lambda text: [sent for sent in     sent_tokenize(text)
if any(True for w in word_tokenize(sent) if w.lower() in words)])
```

It is working but the problem I am facing is if there is/are missing white-spaces after a fullstop in the text I  am getting all such sentences as such.

Example :

```
searched_words = ['snakes','venomous']
text = "I am afraid of snakes.I hate them."
output : ['I am afraid of snakes.I hate them.']
Desired output : ['I am afraid of snakes.']
```

Comment: Can you show or share a sample of the data that you are working on?

Comment: @RohanAmrute It is similar to the example I've illustrated in the question.

Comment: What's happening in tokenize()? Can you replace '.' with '. '? dot and a space

Comment: @themistoklik I've tried the same but in vain! I am losing data in case of abbreviations.

Comment: how about the replacement takes place in the output phase, still loses data?

Comment: The issue is in your data. when you use `sent_tokennize` on `I am afraid of snakes.I hate them.` it does not split into two sentences. if your data would have been like `I am afraid of snakes. I hate them.` then you would have got your desired output.

Comment: Is the use of an external tokenizer agreeable? I can provide a simple answer then .

Comment: @themistoklik Sure come up with your solution keeping in mind that substring match needs to happen as in my case.

Answer (score 1):

If all tokenizers (including nltk) fail you you can take matters into your own hands and try

```
import re
s='I am afraid of snakes.I hate venomous them. Theyre venomous.'
def findall(s,p):
  return [m.start() for m in re.finditer(p, s)]

def find(sent, word):
  res=[]
  indexes = findall(sent,word)

  for index in indexes:
    i = index
    while i>0:
      if sent[i]!='.':
        i-=1
      else:
        break
    end = index+len(word)

    nextFullStop = end + sent[end:].find('.')

    res.append(sent[i:nextFullStop])
    i=0
  return res
```

Play with it [here](https://repl.it/X3G/9503). There's some dots left in there as I do not know what you want to do exactly with them.

What it does is it finds all occurences of said word, and gets you the Sentence all they way back to the previous dot. This is for an edge case only but you can tune it easily, specific to your needs.